# How does Android 8.1 retrieve the battery level of a headset?

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth, headset, android-8.1-oreo

Android 8.1 can show the battery level of a connected headset in the status bar.
How does Android actually do this?

Does it use the AT+IPHONEACCEV command over HFP? Or does it use BLE's battery service if available?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the HCI snoop log and you should find your answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android listens to the vendor specific command

> "AT+IPHONEACCEV=1, ...."

.